# Flex mx:HTML local stylesheet

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I am using an online service that gives me a plain html text. I load this html without problem with my mx:HTML component just by setting the htmlText. My problem is this Html uses a stylesheet that is supposed to exist on my local machine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
  </head>
  ...
```

So the developers sent me the stylesheet.css and I created a folder on my source project and place the stylesheet there src/css/stylesheet.css.

It is not working. Any clues on why and is there a solution for this with the mx:HTML control?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the style class?

```
<!-- STYLES -->

<mx:Style source="css/stylheet.css"/>
```